# How to get the messages count in app insights

Tags: node.js, botframework

I am trying to run the below query and attached is the result of the query. I would like to understand the difference between the conversationupdate, message, event, and endofconversation. Thank you.

```
customEvents 
| where timestamp>ago(7min)
| summarize count=count() by tostring(customDimensions["Activity type"])
```

Here is the result:

[image: Image of message count]

Comment: It sounds like you're wanting definitions of those 4 activity types rather than wanting to know "How to get the messages count in app insights." Could you edit the title of your question to be more accurate?

Comment: Do you still need help?

Answer (score 1):

Those are all activity types. You can find a list of activity types in many places, such as [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-activities-entities?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=cs#activity-types).

> ### conversationUpdate
>
> A bot receives a conversation update activity whenever it has been
>   added to a conversation, other members have been added to or removed
>   from a conversation, or conversation metadata has changed.
>
> ### message
>
> Your bot will send message activities to communicate information to
>   and receive message activities from users. Some messages may simply
>   consist of plain text, while others may contain richer content such as
>   text to be spoken, [suggested
>   actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-add-suggested-actions),
>   [media
>   attachments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-add-media-attachments),
>   [rich
>   cards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-add-media-attachments#send-a-hero-card),
>   and [channel-specific
>   data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-channeldata).
>
> ### event
>
> Your bot may receive an event activity from an external process or
>   service that wants to communicate information to your bot without that
>   information being visible to users. The sender of an event activity
>   typically does not expect the bot to acknowledge receipt in any way.
>
> ### endOfConversation
>
> A bot receives an end of conversation activity to indicate that the
>   user has ended the conversation. A bot may send an end of Conversation
>   activity to indicate to the user that the conversation is ending.